# Anonymous Emailing API PHP/Objective-C

Tags: php, objective-c, xml, ios4

I just wanted to know if there was an api for sending an email with the email address that the email is going to be sent by, set by the user. I would like to do this either via php or objective-c, or any other platform.

Comment: Define "anonymous"? You will need to add some more context to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say you need to create a contact form using HTML and PHP. There are tons of good tutorials for doing this. And yes, you can send anonymous mails with this or with a specific adress...

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
    mail('to@somewhere.com', 'subject', 'message', 'From: from@somewhere.com');
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: But I don't think 90% of the web hosting services allow mail function

Comment: Hmm. I've never encountered that. Works for the ones I've used.